# Exporting and formatting regression analysis results in R to excel

Tags: regression, linear-regression, lm, summary

I am running regression analysis in R and unsure how to export my regression analysis results directly into Excel in standard regression table format (with significance level stars, standard errors, `p-value`, 95% confidence interval, `R-sqr`, `F-test`).

In stata, I would use the `outreg2` command, which automatically generates a regression table, and I was wondering, if R has a similar code?

For example:

```
reg <- lm(imbd_score ~ budget 
+ duration 
+ year 
+ cast_total_facebook_likes, 
data = imbd)

summary(reg)
```

And then exporting this table into excel.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following, I don't know if there exists a smoother procedure, but the trick is to transform regression results in a data.frame object and then export them:

```
install.packages("outreg")
library("outreg")
table<-outreg(OLS, digits = 3L, alpha = c(0.1, 0.05, 0.01), 
       bracket = c("se"), starred = c("coef"), robust = FALSE, small = TRUE,
       constlast = FALSE, norepeat = TRUE)

install.packages("XLConnect")
library("XLConnect")
writeWorksheetToFile("yourdirectory/OLS.xlsx", 
                     data = table, 
                     sheet = "OLS", 
                     header = TRUE,
                     clearSheets = TRUE)
```

OLS is my object created by a lm regression.

Hope this can help,

Silvia D'Andrea